# How to display popular and recent post on fishpig wordpress magento blog page

Tags: fishpig

I have just installed Fishpig extension for wordpress magento. I have installed popular post plugin. But  the widget does not display into blog sidebar.

Comment: And you did add the widget to the sidebar in wordpress?

Comment: The Fishpig Wordpress Integration module integrates only default Wordpress Widgets and the YARPP extension by default. To add a popular posts, you need to extend the Fishpig module.

Answer (score 3):

I know this not the right way but you can get the functionality by following the steps:

**Navigate to your Theme Folder open the file posts.phtml**

*app/design/frontend/your-package/your-theme/template/wordpress/sidebar/widget*

and add the following code before

`<?php endif; ?>`

**The code:**

```
<div class="block block-blog block-recent-posts">
    <?php $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
              $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
              $query = "SELECT `id`, `post_title`,`post_name` , `comment_count` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type`='post' ORDER BY `comment_count` DESC LIMIT 10";
              $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
    ?>
    <div class="block-title">
        <?php echo $this->__('Popular Post');  ?>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($results as $row):?>
            <?php if($row['post_title']!='Auto Draft'):?>
            <li class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('blog/').$row['post_name'];?>"> <?php echo $row['post_title'];?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have already installed Fishpig extension for your Magento store and you also want to display popular or latest/recent posts (with title and image/thumbnail also if you like) into sidebar blog (left or right side) around your site.

To do this you need navigate to location: `/app/design/frontend/your-package/default/template/wordpress/` open the file `sidebar.phtml`

then add the following code into `<div class="wp-sidebar">`

```
    <?php // get post data - OIW
$posts = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection') ->addPostTypeFilter('post')
            ->setOrderByPostDate()
            ->addIsViewableFilter()
            ->setPageSize(10)
            ->load(); ?>
        <?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>

    <div class="block block-list block-articles">

    <div class="block-title">
                <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Latest posts') ?></span></strong>
            </div>


    <div class="block-content">

    <ol id="articles-items">
                    <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>

    <li class="item">
                            <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?></a>
                        </li>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Complimentary to [Sushant's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33864523/529403), if you're using [wordpress-popular-posts](https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/) plugin, and [Magento Fishpig](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) module, you can run any query as follows (Magento 1.x):

```php
$readConnection = Mage::helper('wordpress/database')->getReadAdapter();
$query = "select postid, sum(pageviews), p.*
     from wp_popularpostssummary as wp
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON p.ID = wp.postid
    where `view_date` >= date(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -7 day))
    group by postid
    order by sum(pageviews) DESC
    limit 3
    ";
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

This would run the above query, retrieve the most popular posts in the last 7 days using the Fishpig_Wordpress' module read connection.

Note that the best approach always would be to extend Fishpig module, add new resources to link tables not mapped there, and use [Magento ORM](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-7.html) queries